# What are common reasons of immediately recycling of application pool in IIS using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have uploaded an application to hosting, but its application pools is recycling immediately after logging in, while its is working fine on local IIS. Any common reason facing this scenario?

I need to know What are common reasons of immediately recycling of application pool in IIS using ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: You will have to explain clearly what you meant by "logging in". Also make sure you properly catch and handle ASP.NET unhandled exceptions, before they crash ASP.NET runtime and trigger AppDomain reloads (similar to application pool recycles, but completely a different thing).

Answer (score 0):

iis app pool recycles on iis config file changes or based on the settings in IIS like Number of requests, memory limit, idle time, or scheduled restart. you an check the login time and event vower logs to find out why is app pool is recycling. generally is app poll does not recycle on the user login.